# Joystick -> Keyboard Mapping by Application

Tags: controllers, keyboard, windows

Is there a tool similar to JoyToKey that allows me to create multiple profiles and automatically switch between them depending on which application is being run?

Comment: I'm not sure if this belongs on Arqade; it's not really gaming related.

Comment: Possible, but there are some other questions related to this kind of tool in Arqade (search for JoyToKey), probably because their primary use is for gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Look for xpadder. I am not sure if you can have it switch automatically. But saving and loading multiple configurations are a snap.

Comment: Mhhh... I don't remember that Xpadder switches automatically, but it's really easy to set-up and switch between profiles. Also worth mentioning, that Xpadder is not freeware - It costs about $ 10.

Comment: There are outdated and unsupported versions which I was able to get and use for free. It was from like a tucows or cnet type deal... Seemed legit.